# Display the string with new line with out using \n in jsp

Tags: html, mysql

I have a form with a text area as one of the input fields. I want to store the user entered data. In the process I need to store the `\n` (enter key). But here the problem is in the DataBase (MySql) data is stored, but `\n` is not stored; i.e. data store as:

[image].

When I display the same data in the browser it shows in single line.

[image]

I need to split the data with `\n` and it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> When I display the same data in the browser it shows in single line.

Yes, it would - because a newline in HTML doesn't get *rendered* as a newline. If you look at the raw HTML, I suspect you'll still see the line breaks... it's just that's not how it's rendered.

In order to represent line breaks in HTML, you need to use `<br />` between lines, or something similar - or display it with a `<pre>` tag.

Basically, you need to format your raw text as HTML, however you decide to do that. If you're just dumping the HTML straight into your page, you may well find you already have issues if the text contains HTML tags - they should be escaped.

Comment: I need to split the data with new line and (,).Is there any way to split the data from <pre> tag.

Comment: @kranthi: I'm not sure what you mean, but with the information from my answer you should be able to do some more research, and come up with a new question *if necessary*. In short, the database, spring, jsp and javascript are completely irrelevant here - what you're after is "I've got input string X, and I need to transform it into output HTML Y - this is what I've tried, and here's what I got."

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing \n being stored in database, then you can write logic to include

```
<br/> tag while printing database values on your jsp.
```